# Convergence of $\int _4^\infty \frac{\ln ^{a+1}(x-3)}{\sqrt{e^{x-4}-1}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

I have to investigate convergence of improper integral $\int_4^\infty \frac{\ln ^{a+1}(x-3)}{\sqrt{e^{x-4}-1}}\,dx$.

After substitution $t=x-4$, I got that integral behaves as $\int_0^\infty 
\frac{\ln ^{a+1}(t+1)}{\sqrt{e^t-1}}\,dt$.

This integral has singularities at $0$ and $\infty$. I cannot deduce when integral from $0$ to $1$ converges. Also, I would be grateful if anyone can check my work.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: surely you mean $\ln^{a+1}(t+1)/\sqrt{t}$

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shifting $x$ gives
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+t)^{a+1}}{\sqrt{e^t - 1}}dt.
$$
The only suspicious places in the integrand to check for non-integrability are $0$ and $\infty$.

At infinity, the integrand scales as $\ln(t)^{a+1}e^{-t/2}$. The exponential beats the logarithm no matter how big $a$ is, so this is always integrable.

Near zero, $\ln(1+t)^{a+1}\sim t^{a+1}$, $\sqrt{e^t-1}\sim t^{1/2}$, and thus the integrand scales as $t^{a+1/2}$. This blows up in a non-integrable way if $a+1/2 \le -1$, so the integral converges whenever $a > -3/2$.